# Влияет ли на Seo смена title и url посредством pushState?

Tags: javascript, seo

Здравствуйте. Нашел на гитхабе [плагин](https://github.com/goodcode1/LandingSeo) который добавляет к блокам title, url, description и keywords. Есть ли смысл его использовать на лендинге?

Comment: Вроде бы только гугл исполняет скрипты на странице.

Answer (score 1):

Google *[давно уверяет](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2015/10/deprecating-our-ajax-crawling-scheme.html)*, что без проблем интерпретирует страницы, как мы их видим в браузере:

> Q: I use a JavaScript framework and my webserver serves a pre-rendered
>   page. Is that still ok? A: In general, websites shouldn't pre-render
>   pages only for Google -- we expect that you might pre-render pages for
>   performance benefits for users and that you would follow progressive
>   enhancement guidelines. If you pre-render pages, make sure that the
>   content served to Googlebot matches the user's experience, both how it
>   looks and how it interacts. Serving Googlebot different content than a
>   normal user would see is considered cloaking, and would be against our
>   Webmaster Guidelines.

Яндекс, также достаточно давно *[сообщил](https://yandex.ru/blog/webmaster/21369)* о такой цели.

Так что, мне кажется стоит просто следовать рекомендациям поисковиков, по индексированию такого рода сайтов и не "ломать" логику работы сайта, ради сомнительного удовольствия - *"угадить поисковикам"*. Гугл, абсолютно точно уже прекрасно всё понимает (*[пруф](https://habrahabr.ru/post/314172/)*). На Яндекс пруфа нет, но думается, если сейчас и не понимает, то в ближайшее время станет, так как того требует развитие в области сайтостроения.